# Cannot Add Sales Order with Payment thru REST API

Tags: acumatica

I’m sending a Sales Order with Pre-Authorized Payment thru REST API in Acumatica. This works perfect in my local Acumatica instance. However, I can’t get it worked when switching to Acumatica.com and I’m getting this error “The order cannot be applied, the specified combination of the order type and order number cannot be found in the system.”. It works well when I remove the payment details.

```
<pre><code>
{
  "BillToAddress": {
    "AddressLine1": {
      "value": "3153 Doctors Drive"
    },
    "AddressLine2": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "City": {
      "value": "Los Angeles"
    },
    "Country": {
      "value": "US"
    },
    "PostalCode": {
      "value": "90017"
    },
    "State": {
      "value": "CA"
    },
    "custom": {}
  },
  "BillToAddressOverride": {
    "value": false
  },
  "BillToContact": {
    "Attention": {
      "value": "Mr."
    },
    "BusinessName": {
      "value": "Gregory Luton"
    },
    "Email": {
      "value": "gluton@hotmeal.com"
    },
    "Phone1": {
      "value": "(310) 341-3975"
    },
    "custom": {}
  },
  "CreditHold": {
    "value": false
  },
  "CustomerID": {
    "value": "S000000001"
  },
  "CustomerOrder": {},
  "Date": {
    "value": "2021-06-02T13:42:02.22Z"
  },
  "Description": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "Details": [
    {
      "ManualPrice": {
        "value": true
      },
      "Amount": {
        "value": 79.99
      },
      "DiscountAmount": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "DiscountCode": {},
      "DiscountPercent": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "ExtendedPrice": {
        "value": 79.99
      },
      "FreeItem": {
        "value": false
      },
      "InventoryID": {
        "value": "ELEHDD1"
      },
      "LineDescription": {
        "value": "Lego 500 piece set"
      },
      "LineNbr": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "ManualDiscount": {
        "value": false
      },
      "OpenQty": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "OrderQty": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "RequestedOn": {
        "value": "2021-06-02T13:42:02.22Z"
      },
      "Subitem": {
        "value": ""
      },
      "UnbilledAmount": {
        "value": 79.99
      },
      "UnitPrice": {
        "value": 79.99
      },
      "UOM": {
        "value": "EA"
      },
      "WarehouseID": {
        "value": "WHOLESALE"
      },
      "rowNumber": 1,
      "custom": {}
    }
  ],
  "Hold": {
    "value": false
  },
  "OrderedQty": {
    "value": 1
  },
  "OrderTotal": {
    "value": 79.99
  },
  "OrderType": {
    "value": "SO"
  },
  "Payments": [
    {
      "CardAccountNbr": {
        "value": "CUSTOMPAYMC:S000000001"
      },
      "CashAccount": {
        "value": "10600"
      },
      "CreditCardTransactionInfo": [
        {
          "AuthNbr": {
            "value": "23456"
          },
          "NeedValidation": {
            "value": false
          },
          "TranDate": {
            "value": "2021-06-02T16:13:01.22Z"
          },
          "TranNbr": {
            "value": "12345"
          },
          "TranType": {
            "value": "Authorize Only"
          },
          "custom": {}
        }
      ],
      "Description": {
        "value": "Payment for 006024"
      },
      "PaymentAmount": {
        "value": 79.99
      },
      "PaymentMethod": {
        "value": "CUSTOMPAYMC"
      },
      "ProcessingCenterID": {
        "value": "CUSTOMPAY"
      },
      "Status": {
        "value": "Pre-Authorized"
      },
      "custom": {}
    }
  ],
  "RequestedOn": {
    "value": "2021-06-02T13:42:02.22Z"
  },
  "ShipToAddress": {
    "AddressLine1": {},
    "AddressLine2": {},
    "City": {},
    "Country": {},
    "PostalCode": {},
    "State": {},
    "custom": {}
  },
  "ShipToAddressOverride": {
    "value": false
  },
  "ShipToContact": {
    "Attention": {},
    "BusinessName": {},
    "Email": {},
    "Phone1": {},
    "custom": {}
  },
  "ShipVia": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "Status": {},
  "TaxTotal": {
    "value": 0
  },
  "Totals": {
    "FreightCost": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "DiscountTotal": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "LineTotalAmount": {
      "value": 79.99
    },
    "custom": {}
  },
  "custom": {
    "Document": {
      "AttributeAMT": {
        "value": "79.99",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeAUTHID": {
        "value": "23456",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeCUR": {
        "value": "USD",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeDT": {
        "value": "6/2/2021 4:13:01 PM",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeEXPDATE": {
        "value": "2025-05",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeRC": {
        "value": "0",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeTOKEN": {
        "value": "Gmg9niiBqh8B8FXH",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeTRANID": {
        "value": "12345",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeCID": {
        "value": "B",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      },
      "AttributeSTATUS": {
        "value": "Pending",
        "type": "CustomStringField"
      }
    }
  }
}
</code></pre>
```

```
    public async Task Upsert(BusinessModel.Order 
             order)
        {
            // Map BusinessModel to DTO
            var request = _mapper.Map(order);
            
            //Add Payment record
            DataModel.SalesOrderPayment payment = new 
                   DataModel.SalesOrderPayment();
            payment.Description = new StringValue { Value = 
                  string.Format("Payment for {0}", order.OrderNumber)};
            payment.PaymentMethod = new StringValue { Value = 
                  "CUSTOMPAYMC" };
            payment.CardAccountNbr = new StringValue { Value = 
                   string.Concat(order.PaymentDetails.CardID) };
            payment.CashAccount = new StringValue { Value = "10600" };
            payment.ProcessingCenterID = new StringValue { Value = 
                   "CUSTOMPAY"};
            payment.Hold = new BooleanValue { Value = false };
            payment.PaymentAmount = new DecimalValue { Value = 
                    order.Header.TotalAmount };
            payment.AppliedToOrder = new DecimalValue { Value = 
                    order.Header.TotalAmount };
            payment.Custom = new Dictionary>();
            payment.Status = new StringValue { Value = "Pre-Authorized" 
                     };

            DataModel.SalesOrderCreditCardTransactionDetail detail = new 
                    DataModel.SalesOrderCreditCardTransactionDetail();
            detail.AuthNbr = new StringValue { Value = 
                    order.PaymentDetails.AuthorizationNumber };
            detail.NeedValidation = new BooleanValue { Value = false };
            detail.TranDate = new DateTimeValue { Value = 
                    order.PaymentDetails.AuthorizationDateTime };
            detail.TranNbr = new StringValue { Value = 
                    order.PaymentDetails.TransactionID };
            detail.TranType = new StringValue { Value = "Authorize Only" 
                   };
            detail.Custom = new Dictionary>();
            payment.CreditCardTransactionInfo = new 
                 List();
            //payment.CreditCardTransactionInfo.Add(detail);            

            request.Payments = new List();
            request.Payments.Add(payment);
            
            // Invoke API
            SalesOrder salesOrderResponse = await 
                 api.PutEntityAsync(request, null, null, null, null));
            
            // Map response DTO to BusinessModel
            var response = _mapper.Map 
              (salesOrderResponse);
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post a gist with your json payload?

Comment: Please also check that you have the same version locally and on SaaS

Comment: @DmitriiNaumov yes it has the same versions. I noticed the error shows when I add SalesOrderCreditCardTransactionDetail in the payment.

Comment: What version of Acumatica are you using?  In Acumatica 2019R2, I had success calling the single API with the Payment included.  In 2020R2, I make a separate call to create the Payment after creating the Sales Order.

Also, try specifying the DocType on the Payment to be "Prepayment" or "Payment".